# Run batch file from CMD, that opens exe and passes a string to the exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I have a batch file:

```
@echo off
set STARTTIME=%TIME%

CavSolver.exe %1

set ENDTIME=%TIME%

rem Change formatting for the start and end times
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%STARTTIME%") do (
   set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%ENDTIME%") do (
   set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
set /A elapsed=end-start

rem Format the results for output
set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
if %hh% lss 10 set hh=0%hh%
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
if %cc% lss 10 set cc=0%cc%

set DURATION=%hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%cc%

echo Duration : %DURATION%
```

The batch file is to score the performance of the exe CavSolver.exe against time.

My exe CavSolver.exe prompts user for a string when initialized using C# Console.ReadKey(someString);

I want to be able to use the cmd and type:
    caveroute.bat file1
have the exe take the "file1" as the Console.ReadKey()

how to do this? What I have does not work

Comment: So what is actually your question?

Comment: If you read the last line...

Comment: I am asking becuase the question is unclear

Comment: My bad, I edited it slightly to be more clear... I hope! Thanks

Comment: I am still unclear of what you want. You say you want to have the executable get the file, but that you did already.. `CavSolver.exe %1` so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This does not seem like a batch file question. It seems like you need to program your C# program to accept the proper input.

Comment: Ahh ok, so the batch file is set up correctly? The 1% is the filename given after calling the batch-file? It must be way my C# console is taking in the file?

Comment: If the c# program also reads redirected input, and there is only one input - you might try piping `Echo %1|CavSolver.exe`

Comment: replacing `CavSolver.exe %1` with `%1|CavSolver.exe` worked! First thing my C# did was `_someString = Console.ReadLine();` so wasn't sure why `%1` never worked.... Could you put this as an answer?